# Writing a Between Numbers Function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working through The Craft of Functional Programming 2nd Edition and I have been presented with a task to write a between function which has stumped me.

The function takes three numbers as arguments and returns a boolean result i.e.

```
between :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
```

It is defined so that between m n p is true if n is between n and p. For the sake of simplicity given between 2 2 2, the function would return true, also between 3 3 5 would return true.

Mathematically, x<=y and y<=z

The question also recommended that I could write a weakAscendingOrder function which checks that the number sequence doesn't go down at any point. I have written this function and my code is shown below:

```
weakAscendingOrder :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
weakAscendingOrder x y z = (x <= y) && (y <= z)
```

How can I write a between function, either with or without using weakAscendingOrder, while preserving the function signatures since they have been provided by the book?

Comment: What does "between" mean in this case? Write it out in math notation (using >,<,<=,>=)

Comment: It seems to me that your `weakAscendingOrder` is precisely your `between` function as well. If `y` is between `x` and `z`, then `x >= y` (`y` is at least `x`) and `y <= z` (`y` is at most `z`), which is precisely what `weakAscendingOrder` says.

Comment: This is true actually, I thought that was too simple a solution but maybe it isn't

Comment: Maybe you have to make it so the order of `n` and `p` doesn't matter. In which case: `between m n p = weakAscendingOrder n m p || weakAscendingOrder p m n`

Comment: The task does explicitly state that you are checking whether given m n p, n is the middle number. So would that still make sense if order doesn't matter?

Comment: Ah sorry I assumed `m` was in the middle. You wrote: `if n is between n and p` so that wasn't particularly helpful :-)

Comment: you say "Mathematically, x<=y and y<=z".  The `<=` and `>=` operators happen to be the same in Haskell; the `and` happens to not be the same. Find how the mathematical `and` is spelled in Haskell.  There is an operator spelled `and` in Haskell, and it's closely related, but rather than take 2 arguments, it takes many arguments in a collection type `Foldable a`. For example:  `and [True, True, True]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment two is exactly right. The `weakAscendingOrder` function behaves exactly like you want `between` to behave. Here are some additional flavors of implementation:

```
between x y z --using guards
  |x <= y = y <= z
  |otherwise = False

between x y z = if (x <= y) then (y <= z) else False --using if

between x y z = case (x <= y) of True  -> (y <= z) --using case syntax
                                 False -> False
```

however the `(x<=y)&&(y<=z)` is in my opinion very readable and does the job nicely.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a good reason why the author of the book  suggested the weakAscendingOrder as the help function for (or in) the 'between' function.

To my understanding, the 'between" function is not quite the same as the weakAscendingOrder function, this in the context of the original problem (middleNumber function) presented in the book.